# Reconstructing an expression

Tags: function-construction, algorithm

I have a nested expression like this one

```
expr = Tan[Sin[Cos[x]]];
```

I can deconstruct it with

```
sym = Cases[Level[expr, -1, Heads -> True], _Symbol]
```

> {Tan, Sin, Cos, x}

How can I put it together again? The only way I found is

```
ToExpression @ StringJoin @ Most @ Flatten @
  Transpose[{ToString /@ sym, Table["@", {Length @ sym}]}]
```

> Tan[Sin[Cos[x]]]

Is there a way to do this without using `String` - functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obsolete since 1991 but ... still working and useful:)

```
lst = {Tan, Sin, Cos, x};
Compose @@ lst
(* Tan[Sin[Cos[x]]] *)
```

> [image]

or, `Fold`:

```
foldF = Fold[#2[#] &, #, {##2}] & @@ Reverse@# &;
foldF@lst
(* Tan[Sin[Cos[x]]] *)
```

Comment: +1 Why this function is outdated?? :)

Comment: @ybeltukov, good question:)

Comment: Beat me to it. +1

Comment: @ybeltukov Apparently because someone thinks we are supposed to use `Composition` instead.  That doesn't stop me from using these "retired" functions when I learn about them.  I am also a fan of `ToHeldExpression`.

Comment: @kguler I hurry to accept before this question is (rightfully) closed :)

Answer (score 3):

It is `Composition`

```
list = {Tan, Sin, Cos, x};

(Composition @@ Most@list)@Last@list
(* Tan[Sin[Cos[x]]] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Apply[Apply[Composition, Drop[%, -1]], Take[%, -1]]
```